# Evaluate the integral $\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{\sin x}{6+x^2}\,dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I need to calculate the following integral:
$$\int_{-1}^{1} \frac{\sin x}{6+x^2} dx$$
I have tried trigonometrical substitution like $x=a\tan \theta$ and so on but i cannot solve it ... any ideas?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

If $f$ is an odd function integrable on $[-a,a]$ then
$$\int_{-a}^{a}f(x)\,dx=0$$

Answer (score 1):

the result is zero since the function $$f(x)=\frac{\sin(x)}{6+x^2}$$ is odd.